# Packaging Php Composer inside of Nuget

Tags: npm, composer-php, nuget, package-managers

Does the following make sense: sticking a Composer package (post composer install) inside of a Nuget package for deployment purposes. Or an NPM install result inside of a Nuget package?

In the context of deployment, would it not be best to deploy both types of packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is... No, the scenarios do not make sense.
If you want to wrap up different package managers into a single whole item, use  containers. Nuget is not a container system.

If you don't want to wrap them up, figure out how to deploy for each package manager and build out an appropriate deployment script.